# Django URL Detail

Tags: django, url

I have to assign to work on one Django project. I need to know about the URL say, http://....
Since with ‘urls.py’ we indeed have ‘raw’ information. How I come to know about the complete URL name; mean with

> http+domain+parameters

Amit.

Comment: Are you talking about generating a URL to a specific page on your website?

Answer (score 8):

Look at this snippet :
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1197/

I modified it like this :

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

def site_info(request):
    site_info = {'protocol': request.is_secure() and 'https' or 'http'}
    if Site._meta.installed:
        site_info['domain'] = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        site_info['name'] = Site.objects.get_current().name
    else:
        site_info['domain'] = RequestSite(request).domain
        site_info['name'] = RequestSite(request).name
    site_info['root'] = site_info['protocol'] + '://' + site_info['domain']
    return {'site_info':site_info}
```

The if/else is because of different versions of Django Site API

This snippet is actually a context processor, so you have to  paste it in a file called `context_processors.py` in your application, then add to your settings :

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'name-of-your-app.context_processors.site_info',
)
```

The `+` is here to take care that we d'ont override the possible default context processor set up by django, now or in the future, we just add this one to the tuple.

Finally, make sure that you use `RequestContext` in your views when returning the response, and not just `Context`. This explained [here in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).
It's just a matter of using :

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Hello Guardiola, could you please let me know how I use this in my Project?

Comment: Thanks Guardiola, to assist me; actually I already been used your code like, I defined "def site_info(request):..." it in my 'view.py' file and just use with MIDDLEWARE.Anyway sometime I'll also try this since currently I am bust with some other works and At last but not the least that I am just getting domain name like "http://stackoverflow.com" but what about address "/questions/4921331/django-url-detail" ?

Comment: You can just continue to tweak what this function returns by concatenating other bits like `request.path` , look for Request object in Django docs

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS status would be handled differently by different web servers.

For my Nginx reverse proxy to Apache+WSGI setup, I explicitly set a header that apache (django) can check to see if the connection is secure.

This info would not be available in the URL but in your view request object.

django uses `request.is_secure()` to determine if the connection is secure. How it does so depends on the backend.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure

For example, for mod_python, it's the following code:

```
def is_secure(self):
    try:
        return self._req.is_https()
    except AttributeError:
        # mod_python < 3.2.10 doesn't have req.is_https().
        return self._req.subprocess_env.get('HTTPS', '').lower() in ('on', '1')
```

If you are using a proxy, you will probably find it useful that HTTP Headers are available in HttpRequest.META

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

**Update: if you want to log every secure request, use the above example with a middleware**

```
class LogHttpsMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
            if request.is_secure():
                 protocol = 'https'
            else:
                 protocol = 'http'
            print "%s://www.mydomain.com%s" % (protocol, request.path)
```

Add `LogHttpsMiddleware` to your `settings.py` [`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware-classes)

Comment: I don't know whether information provided by you guys is helpful for me or not, as I already told you I am just novice with Django. Anyway I explain it again what I need it. My application hit web-server with particular urls(http://....) which I don’t know to get data from the database. I want to print those URL somewhere say preferably in command prompt like default log of 'runserver'
07/Feb/2011 19:13:42] "GET /devices/acer/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11595
Hope you would understand my need.

Comment: I understand exactly what you are saying. Use `request.is_secure()` to determine if your backend is detecting a connection as secure (as in `HTTPS`). If you want to print every secure request, use a middleware. I will update with a middleware example that would print all secure requestse.

Comment: Yuji, are you mean to say I have to add def is_secure(self):....in views.py ?; and where I have to add class LogHttpsMiddleware(object):....? and finally in settings.py what I have to write exactly, just LogHttpsMiddleware or django.XXX.XXX...LogHttpsMiddleware! At last I would like to let uou know that I am dealing with Developemt Server (Django default only)

Comment: @Amit, `is_secure` is a method on your `request` object that will return True or False based on whether it thinks the connection is HTTPS or not. You do not need to define it, it is already defined. The middleware can be anywhere, it's just a python object. In settings, simply type the path to the `LogHttpsMiddleware` in python dot syntax to wherever _you decide to put the class_. It would be `myproject.mymodule.LogHttpsMiddleware` if you put it in a file called `mymodule` inside your `myproject`.

Comment: Yuji, I incorporated class LogHttpsMiddleware(object):.....in my app 'views.py' class and correspondingly added in 'settings.py' MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. But nothing was printing with effect of this and when I excluded "if request.is_secure():" I am getting the same log which we get usually in command prompt, runserver say:   Request to path /devices/sonyericsson/ is secure, using https, port 443, etc. //with LogHttpsMiddleware
[07/Feb/2011 20:29:57] "GET /devices/sonyericsson/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16479 //default Log

Comment: @Amit: The dev server does not support HTTPS AFAIK, but looks like the middleware is working. ;)

Comment: Yes Yuji, middleware is working but I am not getting desire output; how I get rid of this? Please help me!

Comment: The dev server does not support HTTPS. It's a dev server!

Comment: You should take a look at the other answer on here for how to construct the full URL if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yuji, as per your suggestion I supercede "def process_request(self, request):" with "def site_info(request):" and as per the code "site_info['root']" would contain desire output but hurdle with me to print this; I tried like: print "LogHttpsMiddleware" % site_info['root'] but it is throwing Error message "TypeError: 'function' object is unsubscriptable". So, could you plz let me know to print "site_info['root']".

Comment: Amit, I've given you all the examples you need to print this information. I've updated the post with simple string formatting and IF ELSE statements to populate a URL.

Comment: yuji, now the output is "http://www.mydomain.com/devices/sonyericsson/" and you can verify it yourself only that it indeed dummy. Would we aberrate??? I need the URL which bringing data from the database (web-server<->database). If you type that URL in web browser as it is then we'll get actual data (let list of devices, more likely list of Sony Ericsson devices if I would select Sony Ericsson)which would be parse later in the program.